# Javascript Loop is not showing result

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, laravel, google-maps

**Problem:**

The javascript loop displays nothing
**Scenario:**

I am passing a Locations Array from Controller to the view.
The locations is working fine when I access it via foreach loop in the view as below

```
@foreach($locations as $location)
                                            <li>{{$location['lat']}} | {{$location['lng']}}</li>
@endforeach
```

Now when I try to access it in JavaScript it prints nothing in the loop.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var locations = {{json_encode($locations)}};


            for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
                alert('Hello');
            }
        });


    </script>
```

**What I want to achieve ?**

Once the loop starts working I want to loop through all locations latitudes and longitudes and display respective markers on the Google Map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON consists of HTML entities (`&quot;`), which is why your JavaScript craps out with `Unexpected token &`.

Could you try changing

```
{{ json_encode($locations) }}
```

with

```
{!! json_encode($locations) !!}
```

**Why**

This is because Laravel automatically escapes HTML when using `{{ }}`, so cross site scripting is prevented.

Usage of `{!! !!}` doesn't escape HTML, but as a result allows cross site scripting if you don't validate your in- and output properly.

Comment: No problem! Should you be interested: `{{ }}` escapes HTML, `{!! !!}` doesn't. Could you tick as an answer so other people can benefit from this? :)

Comment: sure stackoverflow doesn't allow to accept answer at once!

Comment: Ah forgot, no problemo haha